# Toad Formatting: is it possibile to eliminate this statement? /* Formatted on 17/10/2012 12:33:19 (QP5 v5.185.11230.41888) */

Tags: oracle, toad

I don't want Toad to write this statement at the beginning of files and queries:

/* Formatted on 17/10/2012 12:33:19 (QP5 v5.185.11230.41888) */

Is it possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With Toad version 10.6:

- Go to View -> Formatting Options
- Navigate to Oracle Formatter Options -> Header
- Select Tagline: **Disable**

Comment: In version 12.5.1.1, it's View > Toad Options > Formatter > Oracle Formatter Options > Header to get to this option.